# How to pickup requested IPs from a LAN port

Tags: c#

Assuming I had a WiFi router connected to my computer through a LAN cable ([this one](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/wifi-router/tl-wr841n/)).

And assuming I had my phone connected to the WiFi router and would try to visit a website on my phone-browser.

What is the easiest way to pickup the requested website address with my computer?

Comment: What is a requested ip?

Comment: like the IP address my pc is looking for when pinging another computer through intranet

Comment: Is the connected device using dhcp or...?

Comment: Maybe consider reformating you question its not clear what you want to know

Comment: Is that better? :)

Comment: If you care about the ips that are connected to the router i would recommend going to its webinterface. But a more suitable way to do thing for you might be to look at your ARP table (you can do so by typing arp -a in the command prompt

Comment: An ethernet switch would also pickup a requested IP address from whatever port and transmit a response. I want to do the exact same thing with my computer.

Comment: Get a secund network card define your 2 cards to be a bridge and connect your laptop  now you can sniff using wireshark or in code using pcap

Comment: Mainly you should learn about pcap windows will only brong messages up that are directed to your ip address pcap will skip the part or the OS and give you access to all the traffic that arrives on your ethernet port

Comment: I‘ll be using a Linux based system

Comment: But thanks for your answer you can post it in the answer section and I’ll mark it as solution when I get it to work that way. :) btw do I still need to make a bridge using two network cards using pcap? In case of approval is there a way without buying an extra network card?

Comment: With pcap there is no need for a secund card but depending on your routers configuration you might now get all the traffic